# Remove text phrases from SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to change string like :

```
UD12679S ASPL 0001362701 BOSCH Lista EAA152325 EAA 254336 ELSTOCK 01179470 KHD 1179470 KHD LRS02664 LUCAS 560004113 PSH 12030287 ROBERT'S
```

to

```
UD12679S 0001362701 EAA152325 254336 01179470 1179470 LRS02664 560004113 1203028
```

so remove just words without any number. Someone send me this request:

```
SELECT 
    string_agg(wyraz, ' ')  
FROM 
    unnest(string_to_array('UD12679S ASPL 0001362701 BOSCH Lista EAA152325 EAA 254336 ELSTOCK 01179470 KHD 1179470 KHD LRS02664 LUCAS 560004113 PSH 12030287 ROBERT''S'::text, ' ')) x(wyraz) 
WHERE 
    wyraz~'[0-9]'
```

but I'm not good with SQL and I want to have it in request like

```
UPDATE [table] 
SET [column] =
```

Can someone help?

Comment: This is not really an appropriate operation to do in SQL.  Why are you storing these items in a single string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()` and in SQL Server 2017+ you also use `string_agg()`.

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden:

Along with using the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
declare @str varchar(8000) = 'UD12679S ASPL 0001362701 BOSCH Lista EAA152325 EAA 254336 ELSTOCK 01179470 KHD 1179470 KHD LRS02664 LUCAS 560004113 PSH 12030287 ROBERT''S';

select stuff (
  (
  select ' '+s.Item
    from dbo.[delimitedsplit8K](@str,' ') s
    where s.Item like '%[0-9]%'
    order by s.ItemNumber
  for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,1,'')
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/TSXC15231

returns:

```
D12679S 0001362701 EAA152325 254336 01179470 1179470 LRS02664 560004113 12030287
```

---

For an update on a table:

```
create table t (col varchar(8000))
insert into t values ('UD12679S ASPL 0001362701 BOSCH Lista EAA152325 EAA 254336 ELSTOCK 01179470 KHD 1179470 KHD LRS02664 LUCAS 560004113 PSH 12030287 ROBERT''S')

update t
set col = stuff (
  (
  select ' '+s.Item
    from dbo.[delimitedsplit8K](t.col,' ') s
    where s.Item like '%[0-9]%'
    order by s.ItemNumber
  for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,1,'')
```

---

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)
- [Shiny New Toys - `string_split()` and `string_agg()` - Aaron Bertrand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-87-shiny-new-toys/)